# C# - How to display an onscreen notification that can be copied/pasted with standard Windows API?

Tags: c#, notifications

I'm trying to create a C# (VSTA) desktop application that will return data to an onscreen notification, but does not require a form to be built.  It would be best if I could copy and paste from the notification, but it would also be OK to just return the data directly to the clipboard, and display a popup.  Again, no special forms or UI.  This is a script inside of another program.

I've seen applications that have a small yellow window in the upper right hand corner of the application.  It simply displays the output, and disappears after a few seconds. Is that included in any of the Windows dlls?

Comment: We need to know more about what kind of Technology stack you are using. Are you simply running an APSX page or is it a Blazor Page or maybe a C#-react page with API integration.

Comment: In Web terms that is called Toast Notification. In Windows terms its a Balloon Notification. Does that give you enough hint to get started.

Comment: @Cornelius de Jager - This isn't a web application.  It's an internal scripting application. C# scripting in VSTA.